# Importing test files for my code

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

In pycharm I have a directory named my_hw3 with a few python files beneath it named Question_1,Question_2 etc.
To check if my code is right my prof gave a few test files that require me to import a few things.
The part of the test code that imports reads as.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as npr
from my_hw3 import *
```

The part I struggle to understand is the from my_hw3 import *. 
What do I need to change in pycharm in order for my python files to recognize the reference as I seem to always be given the error "unresolved reference".

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/mU9ng.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The directory `my_hw3` will be considered an importable package only if there is an `__init__.py` in it.

If the `Question_n` files are `Question_n.py` files, then you may want to:

```
from my_hw3.Question_1 import *
```

You will probably get better answers if you provide an outline of the complete directory structure for your project.

Comment: I attached a screenshot of my directory and python files. Not sure if that would help.

Comment: `Question_4.py` seems like an independent program, since there are `print()` statements on the module (not in a function). In the end, the good layout will depend on what you want to do. How do you intend to run these programs?